# Converter Char array hh:mm para minutos número

Tags: c++

Estou tentando converter um tempo no formato hh:mm cuja informação esta em uma variável char array, para minutos apenas. Não estou conseguindo converter os pares hh e mm para número para poder realizar calculo. Quanto transformo cada elemento da array char para int, estou obtendo o valor da tabela ASCII mas preciso transformar cada par em número, para poder utilizar em outros cálculos.

O código que desenvolvi até agora foi:

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Converte(int,int,int,int );  // Prototipo da função

int main() {

    char tempo[6] = {'2','1',':','1','7','\0'};  // 21:17

    cout << Converte((int)tempo[0] , (int)tempo[1] , (int)tempo[3] , (int)tempo[4]) << endl;

    // retornou 33485
    // esperado 21 * 60 + 17 = 1277 min

    system("pause");
}
// Antes de enviar para a função foi convertido de char para int
// A função está recebendo o valor decimal ASC de cada caracter - ANALISAR - NÃO É O DESEJADO
int Converte( int tempo0 , int tempo1, int tempo3, int tempo4 ) {  
    int totmin = 0;
    totmin = (tempo0 * 10 + tempo1) * 60 + (tempo3 * 10 + tempo4 );
    return totmin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para transformar um caractere numérico (0,9) em um número propriamente dito, você pode utilizar um calculo simples:

```
numero = caractere - '0';
```

A lógica por trás disso, é que um **char** em c/c++ nada mais é que um número que é exibido no formato **ASCII** (*0* = 48, *2* = 50). Como um **char** é um número, é possível calcular a diferença deles na tabela **ASCII** através de uma simples subtração. Então se você subtrair qualquer **char** que represente um digito pelo char você irá obter o digito no seu formato inteiro.

```
'2' - '0' = 2 => 50 - 48 = 2

'7' - '0' = 7 => 55 - 48 = 7
```

Comment: Olá Rafael. Acredito que este seja o caminho. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Seu calculo está correto, a única coisa que falta é converter da maneira correta. Uma dica é que você não precisa fazer o typecast entre int e char, na prática eles são a mesma coisa só se diferenciam nos limites e na hora de imprimir.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).